# What is this indoor vine with variegated leaves that feel like velvet and are soft to touch?

Tags: identification, houseplants, vines

Please help me identify the plant in pictures below:

[image: plant image]
[image: plant image]

- indoor vine plant.
- variegated.

the leaves are smooth to touch and the petiole/leaf stalk seem to have fuzzy hairs...

Comment: when you say 'velvet texture' do you mean silky or actually velvety (usually because the leaves are covered in soft fuzzy hairs)? One of the images is impossible to magnify and the other one looks like the leaves are not fuzzy, but smooth...